# Failed to boot after system update, Arch linux (Failed to start Hostname Services) and others

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot, pacman

After I updated the system through `pacman`, the system fails to boot. It seems that some services are not started during boot time. It shows like this: Error

[image: Boot errors]

```
Failed to start Hostname Services.
Failed to Start WPA supplicant.
Failed to start Network Manager Script Dispatcher Services.
Failed to start dhcpd on various interfaces.
Failed to start Permit User Sessions.
```

**Solutions I tried:**

1. By using bootable USB,

   1. I mounted the drive,
   2. `arch-chroot` to enter the system,
   3. Updated the packages, re-installed `linux`, `mkinitpcio` and `systemd` as suggested in troubleshooting in arch-wiki.
2. As above method failed, I opened the system in 'rescue' mode and I manually started the services `systemd-hostnamed`, `systemd-user-sessions` and `dhcpd`. Then, my PC booted. And it became normal. But, it did not last.

Next time after reboot, same problem arises. Every time, need to open the system in rescue mode.

Please suggest the solution. I exactly don't know the cause. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have same issue. 
@fra-san: Thank you for the hint, how to get easily more information from logs, so here's what I got from that:

```
Apr 23 22:30:19 myhost systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Failed to create cgroup /system.slice/systemd-hostnamed.service: No such file or directory
Apr 23 22:30:19 myhost systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr 23 22:30:19 myhost systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=219/CGROUP
Apr 23 22:30:19 myhost systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 23 22:30:19 myhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Hostname Service.
```

On my system, after some warm reboots it was starting up again, so looks like timing or race condition issue.

This same issue has been [posted on the Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254980). It turned out to be a bug in dhcpcd 9.0.1 (for details: the [report on Arch's bug tracker](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/66313) and the one on [dhcpcd's mailing list](https://roy.marples.name/archives/dhcpcd-discuss/0002930.html)).
A working temporary solution is to downgrade dhcpcd to a pre-9.0.1 version. The bug was fixed in version 9.0.2.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Since external links can change or become invalid, please edit your post to include at least a summary of the solution you have found in the link you mentioned; you can still keep the link as a reference for "further reading" and to give credit to the original author.

Comment: (CC @AdminBee) I edited your answer, adding a few details about what turned out to be a bug in dhcpcd.

Comment: Downgrading dhcpcd fixed the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm having exactly this issue with package version 9.0.2-1